# How to render formatted post content in widget in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new on wordpress and try to make a widget which will only show the last post of particuler category.

TO do this I have given some settings in admin to select category for which admin wants to display last post (post of last ID).

I am using the below code to in widget to display post content:

```
$query_arguments = array(
        'posts_per_page' => (int) 1,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'cat' => (int) $settings['category'],
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => (($settings['display_by'] == 0) ? 'ID' : 'date')
    );  

$posts_query = new WP_Query( $query_arguments );  
if ($posts_query->have_posts()) {  
    $posts = $posts_query->get_posts();  
    $post = $posts[0];  
    echo $post->post_content;
}
```

But the above code is showing content in one paragraph or you can say that without format. I have done lot of search and found that, I need to apply  "the_content" filter to format the content. So I have done the same as below code:

```
if ($posts_query->have_posts()) {  
    $posts = $posts_query->get_posts();  
    $post = $posts[0]; 
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
    echo $content;
}
```

Now the above changes is returning the null string. I have google lot of things but everyone is saying that to use apply filter or use the_content() function. I have tried both solutions but nothing happening.

Can anyone please share the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

please check whether you are getting any text in $post->post_content
by echo $post->post_content

Comment: are you storing the content in this format <strong>HI  this is the test of the content</strong> if the content is stored in this format in the database than only the text will shown in formatted way

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is,

```
$query_arguments = array(
        'posts_per_page' => (int) 1,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'cat' => (int) $settings['category'],
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => (($settings['display_by'] == 0) ? 'ID' : 'date')
    );  

$posts_query = new WP_Query( $query_arguments );  
while ($posts_query->have_posts()) { 
    $posts_query->the_post();
    echo get_the_content();
}
```

Comment: or use the_content();

Comment: I have already used this, but when I used these functions then wordpress return null value instead of formatted content.